# How to check that a simpleDB domain exists using the AWS SDK for Ruby v2.0

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk, amazon-simpledb

When using the AWS SDK for Ruby v1.0, checking that a simpleDB domain exists was simple:

```rb
def domain_exists?(domain_name)
  sdb =  AWS::SimpleDB.new
  domain = sdb.domains[domain_name]
  domain.exists?
end
```

However, that's no longer possible using v2.0 of AWS SDK for Ruby. How can one check that a simpleDB domain exists using v2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways one can do this.

1. Use `domain_metadata` and catch the exception.

   ```
   def domain_exists?(domain_name)
     sdb = Aws::SimpleDB::Client.new
     sdb.domain_metadata(domain_name: domain_name)
     return true
   rescue Aws::SimpleDB::Errors::NoSuchDomain 
     return false
   end
   ```
2. Reopen the `Aws::SimpleDB::Client` class and add a recursive method `domain_exists?` which uses `list_domains`

   ```
   class Aws::SimpleDB::Client
     def domain_exists?(domain_name, limit = 100, next_token=nil)
       resp = list_domains(next_token: next_token, max_number_of_domains: limit)
       domain_exists = resp.domain_names.include?(domain_name)
       return domain_exists if domain_exists # found the domain
       return domain_exists if resp.next_token.nil? # no more domains to search
       domain_exists?(domain_name, limit, resp.next_token) # more domains to search
     end
   end
   ```

   Then it becomes very simple:

   ```
   def domain_exists?(domain_name, limit = 100)
      sdb = Aws::SimpleDB::Client.new
      sdb.domain_exists?(domain_name, limit)
   end
   ```